# Embedding Bootstrap popover in ng-template Agular 10

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, popover, ng-template

I had come across very strange scenario.

There is a dynamic table in our application comprised of ng-template.

In of the column I was trying to implement Bootstrap 5 Popover.

I tried different packages for the same.

Turned out, the ng-template did not having the code of the popover, and that without showing/throwing any error message.

The solution I found was custom popover using css.

However, I was curious has anyone come across like this?

Possible reason behind this behaviour.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In simple words,

I just was wondering if anyone has implemented the bootstrap popover in ng-template.